# Calculate the multidimensional distance from the center of the galactic space

Tags: r, pca

I have a data matrix called `mydf` which contains the 10 principal components(10 dimensions) in galactic space with 5 samples. I want to find  the centroid (gravitational center) of the samples using all PCs and the the distance for each samples from that centroid. How can we do this in R?

```
   mydf<-  structure(list(Sample = c("1", "2", "4", "5", "6"), PCA.1 = c(0.00338, 
    -0.020373, -0.019842, -0.019161, -0.019594), PCA.2 = c(0.00047, 
    -0.010116, -0.011532, -0.011582, -0.013245), PCA.3 = c(-0.008787, 
    0.001412, 0.003751, 0.00371, 0.004242), PCA.4 = c(0.011242, 0.000882, 
    -0.003662, -0.002206, -0.002449), PCA.5 = c(0.055873, -0.022664, 
    -0.014058, -0.024757, -0.020033), PCA.6 = c(-0.001511, 0.006226, 
    -0.005417, 0.000522, -0.003114), PCA.7 = c(-0.056734, -0.007418, 
    -0.01043, -0.006961, -0.006006), PCA.8 = c(0.005189, 0.008031, 
    -0.002979, 0.000743, 0.006276), PCA.9 = c(0.008169, -0.000265, 
    0.010893, 0.003233, 0.007316), PCA.10 = c(-0.000461, -0.003893, 
    0.008549, 0.005556, -0.001499)), .Names = c("Sample", "PCA.1", 
    "PCA.2", "PCA.3", "PCA.4", "PCA.5", "PCA.6", "PCA.7", "PCA.8", 
    "PCA.9", "PCA.10"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

For example, this is the PCA plot (obviously in 2D) for these 5 samples for which I need to find the centroid using all 10 dimensions first. Then need to calculate the distance for each sample from that one centroid.

[image]

Comment: Your plot was apparently meant to be a projection of the points in a 10 dimensional space onto the plane formed by the first two axes, but you instead used the first column so it was just the "Sample" values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it would be that difficult to show that for equally weighted masses at the ten-dimensional points given by those 5 vectors that the sum of squared distances from a point would be minimized for a point at:

```
> centroid = colMeans(mydf[-1])

> centroid
     PCA.1      PCA.2      PCA.3      PCA.4      PCA.5      PCA.6      PCA.7      PCA.8      PCA.9     PCA.10 
-0.0151180 -0.0092010  0.0008656  0.0007614 -0.0051278 -0.0006588 -0.0175098  0.0034520  0.0058692  0.0016504
```

And then the distances would be:

```
 > rowSums( sweep(mydf[-1], 2, centroid, "-")^2 )
           1            2            3            4            5 
0.0059118459 0.0005748535 0.0003223413 0.0005664300 0.0004386126
```

For plotting the values in the first two "dimensions" I would use this instead:

```
with(mydf, plot(PCA.2  ~    PCA.1 ))
points( x= -0.0151180, y= -0.0092010, col='red', pch=24)
```

Comment: So when you are doing this `> rowSums( sweep(mydf[-1], 2, centroid, "-")^2 )`, are you actually calculating the distance from the mean of all components (10 centroids) or from the mean of the centroids (one galactic space) to every individual?

Comment: I'm doing both. The 5 points were necessarily coplanar in a 10 dimensional space, so I was sure it would succeed in this situation. I was not as certain that this would succeed if there were more than 10 points.